# Unique Values in Excel are not accurate with column that has a formula

Tags: excel, vba

I am currently using this code to pull unique values from Column A that are not present in Column B.

In Column B, I have a substitute formula to remove underscores from values in Column C.

Previously, I had it working with only the values in Columns A and B as pasted values from a Chrome browser. However, the substitute is messing my comparing unique values because it sometimes pulls values that are not unique from Column A.

I thought copying and pasting the values with a paste special might work, but it still picked up the duplicate value. I also tried formatting the column to text, but that did not work so well either.

Please note, these values are being copied from a web page. I have a feeling that may be part of the problem.

Here is my code at the moment. It works for columns without formulas, but once there is a formula, the results are no longer accurate.

```
Sub PullUniques()
    Dim rngCell As Range
    Dim ws As Worksheet


   Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("D2:D150").Clear
   Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("E2:E150").Clear

    For Each rngCell In Range("A2:A150")
        If WorksheetFunction.CountIf(Range("B2:B150"), rngCell) = 0 Then
            Range("D" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Offset(1) = rngCell
        End If
    Next
    For Each rngCell In Range("B2:B150")
        If WorksheetFunction.CountIf(Range("A2:A150"), rngCell) = 0 Then
            Range("E" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Offset(1) = rngCell
        End If
    Next

Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("A2:A150").Font.Size = 8
Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("B2:B150").Font.Size = 8
End Sub
```

The data being entered is a list of items formatted as follows from an html table.

```
>NAM_Cards_CRS Consumer Service_FR
>NAM_Cards_CRS Consumer Service_ABC
>NAM_Cards_CRS Consumer Service_DEF
>NAM_Cards_CRS Consumer Service_GHI
>NAM_Cards_CRS Consumer Service_THD
```

It is copied into C2, and the rest pastes below it, and I put the Substitute code into B2 and below with the underscore.

Comment: Code looks OK so likely the issue is in your source data.  If you can post an example of what's going wrong that would help.

Comment: What's the Substitute formula in column B?

Comment: SUBSTITUTE (C2, "_", " "). The data is coming from an html table. Copied and pasted manually. I was originally converting it to text, but I am not sure I did it right. I have since removed that part of the code.